# Two Variables as cell references

Tags: string, vba, loops, variables

I'm having an issue with a macro that I'm writing that is below. To boil it down, I have removed all the non-relevant parts of the code to make it easier.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim a As Integer
For a = 2 To 21
Dim y As Integer
For y = 27 To 47
If InStr(Cells(a, y), “SUB”) > 0 Then
Range(Cells(a, y), Cells(a, (y + 2))).Select
Selection.Cut
Cells(a, 22).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
Next y
Next a
End Sub
```

What is happening is that it is cutting and pasting all the ranges for y=27 to y=47 instead of just the cells that would pass the IF statement. I suspect this has to do with using variables for both the column and row identifiers but don't know.

What it's supposed to do is find a cell that contains "SUB," then copy that cells and the 2 cells to its right and paste them into the same row, but columns 22-24.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: 'Would pass the IF statement'. Have you checked that not all of them do pass the if? Step through your code with F8, so you can see what's happening on execution.

Comment: Perhaps some of the "non-relevant parts of the code" are relevant after all. The code that you show is fairly straightforward (even if it uses `Select` too much) and doesn't account for what you describe.

Comment: JZZ: Looking through, most of the cells are blank so there's no reason for them to pass the if statement. 

To John: I say that the other parts of the code are irrelevant to the problem because when it is stripped down to this, I get an identical issue to what I get from the full version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing obvious wrong with the code you posted, but it could be improved/shortened by removing the selections

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim a As Long, y As Long

    For a = 2 To 21
        For y = 27 To 47
            If InStr(Cells(a, y), "SUB") > 0 Then
                Cells(a, y).Resize(1, 3).Cut Cells(a, 22)
            End If
        Next y
    Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: While this is great and makes the macro run noticeably faster, after it has finished, Cells(a, 22) still ends up with the value that was originally in Cells(a, 47) and any values that were in the Cells(a,27) to Cells(a, 49) have been cleared.

Comment: That's not what I see in my testing.  Are you using exactly the code I posted?  Do you have any event handlers running on the worksheet?

Comment: I have no idea how this happened, but after the exact code you wrote didn't work, I deleted and retyped the "SUB" part and now it works perfectly. I beg someone to explain that particular quirk of excel to me.

Comment: So Thank you Tim for your help

Comment: Looks like the quotes around SUB in your question's code had become "smart quotes" (I just fixed that in my code).  However, smart quotes typically give you a compile error in the VB editor...